# The Name DoEditButtonChecked does not exist in the current context C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Very new to all this. Was working on my game in unity and got an error. I tried restarting unity, I tried asking for help in other places, and got no response. I don't really know how to debug it, or really any error.

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.spriteshape@3.0.14\Editor\SpriteShapeControllerEditor.cs(352,38): error CS0103: The name 'DoEditButtonChecked' does not exist in the current context

Comment: var hasEditToolChanged = DoEditButtonChecked<SpriteShapeEditorTool>(PathEditorToolContents.icon, Contents.editSplineLabel);
            if (hasEditToolChanged && !UnityEditor.EditorTools.ToolManager.activeToolType.Equals(typeof(SpriteShapeEditorTool)))
                SpriteShapeUpdateCache.UpdateCache(targets);

im using  a microgame on unity and don't know any C#. Only Lua and JS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What Unity version are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it by updating all the packages from the project direcltly in unity. Go to the manage services window (It is the cloud found in the upper part next to your account), then click the package manager and update all the ones that are not in green. Hope it helps you.